# bind spring controllers to a root controller

Tags: java, spring, controller

I have several end points that have the same request Mapping :

```
@RequestMapping("/api/client/personal")
@RequestMapping("/api/client/finance")
@RequestMapping("/api/client/contacts")
@RequestMapping("/api/client/job")
```

I want to find a way to have a root controller with `@RequestMapping("/api/client")` 
that bind the calls

```
@RequestMapping("/personal")
@RequestMapping("/finance")
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
@RequestMapping("/job")
```

to their right controllers. How may I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

you'll need a polymorphic parent class
Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/client")
public class RootController {
    //generic root controller stuff
}

@RequestMapping("/personal")
public class PersonalController extends RootController {
    //personal controller specific
}
```

Comment: Yes...this may be a solution

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to declare them as different classes? there is always the option to have them in different files with similar requestMapping paths ex:
`@RequestMapping("/api/client")
public class RootController{}

@RequestMapping("/api/client/personal")
public class PersonalController{}`

Comment: it is only to not declare the same the controllers ... what is the option ?

Comment: the option is to declare them in different classes and different files. you could have a java class named RootController.java that would look somthing like `import ...
@RequestMapping("/api/client")
public class RootController {
    // root controller stuff
}` class named PersonalController.java
`import ...
@RequestMapping("/api/client/personal")
public class PersonalController {
    // personal controller stuff
}`

Comment: the classes won't be linked together (which they don't have to be) they will be joined via the path you are requesting. `@RequestMapping(...)`

Comment: Yes this is what I was doing and I though that it is not a good idea .. but it is not very critical :) thanks for your help

Comment: personally i like everything declared in different classes/files, it makes it easier to maintain since you don't have to weed thru the mess of things that aren't related to your issue

Answer (score 0):

May this be a solution ?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/client")
public class RootController {

    @Autowired
    PersonalController personalController;

    @Autowired
    FinanceController financeController;

    @RequestMapping("/personal")
    public PersonalController personalController() {
        return personalController;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/finance")
    public FinanceController financeController() {
        return financeController;
    }
}
```